# Can't get variable from Notification?

Tags: xcode, swift4, appdelegate

I want to write a project has a notification can print data which stored in main viewcontroller, but when notification fired, always get empty data.

In the ViewController

```
arrPerson = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrPerson.append("Peter")
    arrPerson.append("Jack")

setNotification()
}

func printTheName() {
    print("In printTheName")
    print("arrPerson:\(arrPerson.count)")
    for x in arrPerson {
        print(x)
    }
}

func setNotification() {

    let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notification.title = "title"
    notification.subtitle = ""
    notification.body = "body"
    notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "check", content: notification, trigger: trigger)

    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("notificationCenter.add ERROR:\(error)")
            // Handle any errors.
        }
    }
}
```

In the Appdelegate

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("In userNotificationCenter")
    ViewController().printTheName()
}
```

The code will print out "userNotificationCenter","In printTheName","arrPerson:0".

I need get data from notification. Why arrPerson.count is 0 when call  printTheName from notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to programatically instantiate the viewController using a window in your appdelegate.
You will be able to fetch the count then in your notification center.Or since your viewController class is the landing screen, Call the userNotifationCenter method in your main Class and not here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but userNotifationCenter is called by system when notification is fired(Am I wrong?), how to call from viewcontroller by user programatically?

Comment: You will need to implement its delegate method. Please find the required link for the implementation.  https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/usernotifications-in-swift-3-part-1-d250e54440c1

Comment: Alright,  I will take a look this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, that's my misunderstand, it's works now, thank you.